# Vimeo Aframe can you show me an example of working play pause buttons?

Tags: aframe, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am trying to add play and pause buttons to VIMEO in WebXR via Aframe (and disable autoplay).

Note the video is playing on autoplay on the desktop web browser, but it is not playing at all inside the same website via the Lenovo Mirage Solo.

So to try to get it working I attempted to disable autoplay, however it's ignoring my command, and I tried to create play pause function that will play the video on mouse enter and pause the video on mouse leave.

How do I do this the correct way?

Example code:

```
  AFRAME.registerComponent("play", {
    init: function () {
        this.el.addEventListener("mouseenter", (e) => {
               VR_LOG('mouseenter')
               this.el.play();
              });
        this.el.addEventListener("mouseleave", (e) => {
               VR_LOG('mouseexit')
               this.el.pause();
              });


    }
});

<a-entity autoplay="false" vimeo="id: 322980501" play>
<a-plane  id="spectrum" class="clickable" color="#000000" scale="3.2 1.8" position="0.0 1 -2"></a-plane>
```

Can you post an example of vimeo in aframe with autoplay false and with a working play and pause button?

Update: The play pause function started working when I moved the play component to the parent entity, but the autoplay is still autoplaying. And it still doesn't play at all in the Firefox Reality browser on the lenovo Mirage Solo for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `autoplay: false` inside the `vimeo` entity arguments, it should look something like

```html
<a-entity vimeo="id: 322980501; autoplay: false;" />
```

Unfortunately, I can't test on the Lenovo Mirage but feel free to [open a Github issue](https://github.com/vimeo/aframe-vimeo-component/issues/new) and so we can try and help solve that

We are working on posting a playback control example soon, but [here is an open issue with more information about how to get that working](https://github.com/vimeo/aframe-vimeo-component/issues/11)